# How can i sort groups ascending with specific value at the end in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I got a Crystal Report with data grouped by a field, for example 'height' and I want to sort in a specific order. I want to sort it ascending but with height = 0 at the end. Is that somehow possible.

In Java or so i would use a custom comparator.

thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

create a formula

```
if {field} = 0 then 99999 then 0 else {field}
```

sort on that but dont place in report of course

Answer (score -1):

Find "Record Sort Expert"... Put a field and choose ASC/DESC there.

You need to do custom sorting by formula to skip that one. OK, put a ASC for that field, but in the "Display String" property of that field make a conditional formula for hiding that one or changing the value of it. 
Here is some pseudo code... IF {field_height} == 0 then SET_LASTPOSITION else {field_height}. I hope this will help a bit.

Comment: but then 0 is at the biginning: 0,2,5,6 or in case of DESC 6,5,2,0. I want 2,5,6,0

Comment: Ideally, you should have updated your answer. The OP has clearly mentioned all 0's in the end.